# Массив символов преобразовать в строку

Tags: java

Какие есть варианты преобразовать массив символов в строку?
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
char[] array = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
String string = String.valueOf(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] array = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
String string = new String(array);
```